# read file into two dimensional array

Tags: java, java-io

I am trying to read a file into a two dimensional array.
When I read it in, in the first section, the values are correct.
When I write it out, the values are all have the value "10".
How can I fix this?

```
public static void readagain() {

     try {
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream("C:\\test.new");
            int m = 16;
            int n = 16;
            int[][] a = new int[m][n];
            int value=0; 

            while ((value = is.read()) != -1) { 
                for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                       try{
                        a[i][j] = value;
                           System.out.println("number is "+ a[i][j]);
                        }
                       catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }//j
                } //i         
            } 

            for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                        System.out.println("number is "+a[i][j]);
                    }
                }
        } 
      catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: What is the point of your while loop?

Answer (score 3):

Your first loop looks like it will populate your entire array with whatever the last value is, and it will all be the same.

what seems to be happening, is you take value after value, and then you over-write all the values in the array every time.

I'd recommend just using 1 loop, and calculating what `i` and `j` ought to be for instance:

```
for( int x=0-; (value = is.read()) != -1) && x < m*n; x++) { 

   int i = x/n;
   int j = x%n;
   try{
    a[i][j] = value;
       System.out.println("number is "+ a[i][j]);
    }
   catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error has to do with the sequence in which you are performing operations.
If we lay out your code flow the steps are.

1. Read the next value from the Input Stream.
2. Iterate over all the positions in your two dimensional array
3. While iterating write the value you read into the current array position

The problem here is you read one value and then proceed to write that value into every index in your array. Thus, when you are done the array will contain the last value read in every index.

Answer (score 0):

Your looping is wrong. The last value read is being set all over the array again. Reading values within for loop would work.

```
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      try{
        int value = is.read();
        if (value == -1) break;
         a[i][j] = value;
         System.out.println("number is "+ a[i][j]);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }//j
 } //i
```

Answer (score 0):

is.read will return you the byte valu 0-255 you need to convert it to char and check if its a line break.
If it is a line break then increase the present row.

```
int row = 0;
int col=0;
while ((value = is.read()) != -1) { 
    if(((char) value) == '\n'){
        row++;
        col=0;
    }
    a[row][col++] = value;

}
```